# No outgoing network after Amazon restarted EC2 instances

Tags: linux, networking, amazon-web-services

Today Amazon had to reboot its instances, and now our production servers have no outgoing connections. (Nothing was changed in AWS console security groups)

I'm trying to ping Google (8.8.8.8) and get no response. But when I ping the servers between each other they connect.

What information would be needed to troubleshoot this? How could I get Internet connectivity again?

ifconfig

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 06:63:61:f8:dc:bc
          inet addr:192.168.1.11  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::463:61ff:fef8:dcbc/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:9001  Metric:1
          RX packets:413185 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:462710 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:200809359 (191.5 MiB)  TX bytes:122009183 (116.3 MiB)
          Interrupt:24

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:127991 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:127991 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:62428475 (59.5 MiB)  TX bytes:62428475 (59.5 MiB)
```

and in AWS security groups it is open to all (just to clarify it worked before the restart)

Comment: Your network configuration, both server-side (`ifconfig`) and from the EC2 control panel, would certainly help.

Comment: Since you have a 192.168 address, this suggests this is a VPC instance, which suggests you also have a NAT instance providing Internet access service for this instance.  If so, you need to troubleshoot why that machine, perhaps, isn't doing what it should.  Are you familiar with the concept I'm discussing? Did you build the NAT instance yourself, or are you using the stock AWS image for it?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your NAT instance also bounced and didn't come back...Or perhaps you had it in a scaling group and the scaling group brought up a new NAT instance but didn't update the route or source/destination check.

Three things to check...

1. is the NAT instance up & functioning?  If not, terminate it & create a new one.
2. Is the Source/Destination checking disabled on the NAT instance?  To check, go to the EC2 console, select your instance, and it should say '''Source/Dest Check: False''' under the description box. If it is True, select the instance, go to actions, Change Source/Dest Check.
3. Is the routing set up correctly?  Go to your VPC dashboard, Subnets, pick the Private subnet that isn't routing, look at the Route Table, for Destination 0.0.0.0/0 it should be pointing to the ENI of the instance running your NAT. Hopefully it doesn't say "Black Hole."

Note that if you're not in a private subnet, the route would point to an IGW-xxxxx instead of an ENI-xxxxx / I-xxxxxx